# why is va_arg returning wrong data?

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, embedded

I am trying to port an embedded OS to a new platform and I am facing some problems with the filesystem component.
I stepped in the code to finally localize the problem:
The function call relevant to my case is

```
    // int64_t vnid = 1;
    // int32_t vid = 0;
    ...
    vnode = queue_lookup (& vnode_manager . vnode_list,
                vnode_id_inspector, vnid, vid);
```

And here is the *queue_lookup* declaration:

```
    void * queue_lookup (queue_t * queue, queue_inspector_t inspector, ...)
    {
      bool result;
      va_list list, list_copy;
      queue_link_t * item = NULL;

      va_start (list, inspector);

      if (queue -> status != 0)
      {
        for (item = queue -> head; item != NULL; item = item -> next)
        {
          result = false;

          va_copy (list_copy, list);
          result = inspector (item, list_copy);
          va_end (list_copy);

          if (result) break;
        }
      }

      va_end (list);
      return item;
    }
```

and finally, here is the *vnode_id_inspector* declaration:

```
    bool vnode_id_inspector (void * node, va_list list)
    {
      vnode_t vnode = node;
      int64_t vnid = va_arg (list, int64_t);
      int32_t vid = va_arg (list, int32_t);

      watch (bool)
      {
        ensure (vnode != NULL, false);
        return vnode -> id == vnid && vnode -> volume -> id == vid;
      }
    }
```

Now the problem is when I call queue_lookup with vnid=1 and vid=0, I get vnid=1 and vid=1145248 in the vnode_id_inspector !

How can I fix this issue with as minimum code change as possible ?

Regards,

Edit: add some debug info

```
    (gdb) p vnode_manager . vnode_list
    $44 = {lock = 1, head = 0x167770, tail = 0x167770, status = 1}
    (gdb) p vnode_manager . vnode_list ->head
    $45 = (queue_link_t *) 0x167770
    (gdb) p *(vnode_t)vnode_manager . vnode_list ->head
    $46 = {link = {next = 0x0}, id = 1, volume = 0x166370, destroy = false, 
      usage_counter = 1, data = 0x166430}
    (gdb) p *(volume_t)((vnode_t)vnode_manager . vnode_list ->head)->volume
    $47 = {link = {next = 0x0}, id = 0, root_vnid = 1, lock = 0, host_volume = 0x0, 
      host_vnid = -1, cmd = 0x13a768 <rootfs_cmd>, data = 0x1663d0}
```

Comment: Is the type for vid and vnid correct ?

Comment: Yes types are correct !

Comment: `int64_t` != `uint64_t`, are they? What is this: `& vnode_manager . vnode_list,`?

Comment: it's int64_t in both locations! spelling mistake !

Comment: Separate problem: you are calling va_end( copy_list ) on an invalid pointer.

Comment: Check the posting update, I included some debug infos

Comment: I think your problem might be somewhere else, try creating a simple test using variable arguments.

Comment: I got something wierder now:
When I make the call in the system kickstart function every thing is OK, but when I call it from my main I get this problem !
variable arguments are working fine in printf among other functions

Comment: You should put the solution in an answer instead of editing your question and adding it there. It is allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, there was a problem in the stack alignment. I fixed it by making some adjustment in the cpu_context_switch.s to align the stack to **8bytes** instead of **4bytes**.